# How to reuse plugin configuration without inheriting from parent pom

Tags: maven

We have a multi module project with a root pom.

```
    Root
    |->a
    |->b
    |->c
    |->d
```

The parent pom for a,b,c and d is "X" which isn't owned by us, so I can't do any modifications here.

Also I can't change my parent as all my child projects are dependent on "X".

The problem that I face is I'm duplicating the same plugin configuration in all the submodules as I can't add the configuration to the centralized parent and inherit the same.

Can anyone suggest me how to reuse the plugin configurations in all child modules instead of duplicating it?

Comment: If you have a multi module project where each child inherits not from your own root this is usually not Ok..better make root a pom which inherits from X and there you can control the configuration...BTW: Please edit your post and format it correctly makes it easier to read...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the required plugin configurations are in X, then you should do nothing, because plugins are inherited.

If X doesn't have the required plugin configurations, you can create a pom that will be a common root of your A,B,C,D modules:

The hierarchy will be:

```
X
|__ MY_CUSTOM_ROOT
    |__ A
    |__ B
    |__ C
    |__ D
```

This `MY_CUSTOM_ROOT` will contain the plugin definitions that will be inherited automatically A,B,C,D

If you want to make sure what exactly gets inherited, use `mvn help:effective-pom`